# How to transfer files from a bluetooth-connected device using the command line (with middle-level commands)

Tags: command-line, bluetooth, file-transfer, file-browser

#### Situation

I am working with Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04.

After extensive research for another [post on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1222672) I am looking for alternatives to the pair BlueZ/Blueman for transferring files via Bluetooth.

This is because these pieces of software, beside not working for me on the spot, have been developing towards the removal of **file browsing** capabilities.
Thanks to that I could use my file manager or a terminal to look into and work with the content of my mobile.
See "Drop browse feature" in their [changelog for version 2.1 onwards](https://askubuntu.com/q/1222672/446253), for example.

If I understand this correctly, would I want to transfer any number of pictures from my Bluetooth-connected mobile into a computer, I ought to send them in batches from the mobile, as suggested from example [in this other post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1157025).
This is unhandy.

#### Questions

"Middle levels", as in the title, are those sorts of commands invoked under the hood by Bluez, Blueman and suchlike, so one level of refinement below their own. I am glad to learn this. Eventually I might use a script.

Therefore, I would ask some guidance, say a 'canonical answer', on using the command line (bash)

1. to establish a Bluetooth connection between a computer and an external device;
2. to make the content of the remote device browsable (á la `ls`) from the receiving computer;

assuming all necessary hardware is up and running.

#### Note

I do rule out the assistance of helping programs like Bluez etc. If there are working self-contained alternatives to Bluez/Blueman, I am glad to hear of them. However, the wish is to have a canonical answer with a long breath, overcoming the limitation of several outdated answers on SE.

Comment: What are with middle-level commands?

Comment: Is you question: "How can I mount the file-system of my phone, on by Gnu/Linux device, using blue-tooth? -- so that I can transfer files" ?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor If you feel that your formulation addresses points 1 and 2, please feel free to read it like that. To me it sounds fine. Middle levels are those commands that are possibly invoked by Bluez and Blueman under the hood, which have commands of their own.

Comment: My comments are to help you improve your question, so that you can get it answered. I feel that improving the question will have a bigger effect than the bounty (Yes I want the bounty, but I have no idea what you are trying to do, so I move on). If my one line summary is the same as your many paragraphs, then I would suggest using it as a tile, or at least some where near the top of the question (if only one of the possible acceptable outcomes).